# Font Awesome icon behind text

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to make an icon appear behind some text, but it isn't working.
The CSS I have used for the icon is link this:

```
.fa:not(.form-control-feedback) {
    font-size: $h1-size;
    color: lighten($brand-color-light, 10%);
    z-index: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: -webkit-box; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

and the html is like this:

```
<a ui-sref="account({ accountNumber: controller.account.accountNumber })" animated-tile>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

    <div style="z-index: 2;">
        <h3>{{ controller.account.accountNumber }}</h3>
        <h5>{{ controller.account.name }}</h5>

        <p>
            {{ controller.account.address.houseName }}<br ng-if="controller.account.address.houseName.replace(' ', '')" />
            {{ controller.account.address.street }}<br ng-if="controller.account.address.street.replace(' ', '')" />
            {{ controller.account.address.town }}<br ng-if="controller.account.address.town.replace(' ', '')" />
            {{ controller.account.address.county }}<br ng-if="controller.account.address.county.replace(' ', '')" />
            {{ controller.account.address.postCode }}
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

but the text just appears behind the icon.
I have tried using :before and it still doesn't work.

Here is a codepen of my issue:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/GZeLQM

and here is one where I set it :before

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/EKMJLj

anyone know how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add position relative to h3 and p, or put them in a div and add position relative to the div.

```css
.tile {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.tile h3,
.tile p {
  position: relative;
}
.tile .fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 tile">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      <h3>This is a test</h3>
      <p>This is an issue when the text is behind the actual font-awesome icon. Does anyone know how to solve it?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have marked yours as the answer over the rest because the only thing I needed was to make the text (or containing div) relative and you were the only one that said it, although others actually had it in their solution, they never said that is all I actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `z-index` for this, as `::after` or `::before` are just the name of pseudo elements and moreover, since you are using `position: absolute`:

```css
.tile {
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.tile .fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tile p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 tile">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      <h3>This is a test</h3>
      <p>This is an issue when the text is behind the actual font-awesome icon. Does anyone know how to solve it?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the preview in full screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to add `z-index : 1;` to class name `.tile .fa {....}` and with it add this css `.tile p {  z-index : 2;  position: absolute; }` **or**
Copy and past this below css in to your present css will resolve issue

```
.tile .fa {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index : 1 ;
}

.tile p {
  z-index : 2;
  position: absolute;
}
```